# Jet Zoom Star Plugins alert when image loaded

Tags: javascript

How do you use this:

```
JetZoom.jetzoom_ready()
```

Its at the very bottom of this page: http://www.starplugins.com/jetzoom/api

say I want to say alert("loaded") when the zoom image has loaded.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#myJetZoomImage').bind('jetzoom_ready', function() {
 alert('loaded');
 });
```

Obviously, #myJetZoomImage would be a selector to the image with Jet Zoom applied to it.